# Multi level dynamic list jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

On click list element should expand (show) childs and after second click it should colapse all again.
I made this: https://jsfiddle.net/Zydnar/o6wkobfv/3/

```
<ol id="list">
    List title
    <li onclick="fajnalista(this)">
        Item 1
        <ol>
            <li class="list_child"></li>
            <li class="list_child"></li>
            <li class="list_child"></li>
            <li class="list_child"></li>
            <li class="list_child"></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li onclick="fajnalista(this)">
        Item 2
        <ol>
            <li class="list_child"></li>
            <li class="list_child"></li>
            <li class="list_child"></li>
            <li class="list_child"></li>
            <li class="list_child"></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

```css
#list {
    list-style-type: circle;
}
.list_child {
    visibility: collapse;
    height: 0px;
}
```

```js
function fajnalista(dis){
    $(dis).find(".list_child").toggle().css({ "list-style-type": "square" });
    $(dis).find(".list_child").toggle().css({ "visibility": "visible" });
    $(dis).find(".list_child").toggle().css({ "height": "initial" });
}
```

but there is one problem - when I remove second line, or when I move it  doesn't work properly. Actually "list-style-type" should be toggled for expanded "li" not for its childs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should work :) The only problem was in my understanding of toggle() in jQuery.
https://jsfiddle.net/Zydnar/o6wkobfv/4/

```
function fajnalista(dis) {
        var enabled = true;
        if ($(dis).find(".list_child").css("visibility") === "collapse") {
            enabled = false;
        }
        if (!enabled) {
            $(dis).find(".list_child").css({
                "visibility": "visible",
                "height": "initial",
                "list-style-type": "square"
            });
        }
        else {
            $(dis).find(".list_child").css({
                "visibility": "collapse",
                "height": "0",
                "list-style-type": "square"
            });
        }}
```